# Как в 1С программно обращаться к номеру инвентаризации ОС?

Tags: 1с

Указал скриншотом номер инвентаризации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как программно обращаться к номеру инвентаризации ОС?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего это реквизит табличной части ОС документа ИнвентаризацияОС. Обратите внимание в левой панели она видна. Если это так, то ниже пример перебора табличной части с выводом значений указанного реквизита:

```
Для каждого ТекСтрока из ДокИнв.ОС Цикл
   Сообщить(ТекСтрока.ИнвентариныйНомер);
КонецЦикла;
```

То есть по факту вам необходимо получать строку табличной части, и затем вы можете работать с реквизитами полученной строки.

Comment: У меня пишет что `ИнвентарныйНомер` отсутствует. Посмотрел его подробнее, он оказывается имеет тип колонка реквизитов. А обычные реквизиты отображаются (они синие, а колонка реквизитов красные). Как вывести колонку реквизитов?

Comment: У вас управляемое приложение, то есть идет деление Клиент-Сервер. Мой код попробуйте выполнить в процедуре с директивой "НаСервере".
Есть Объект со всеми реквизитами, а есть форма документа, которая по факту отображает информацию. Что бы работать с элементами формы, попробуйте что то типа "ЭлементыФормы.НазваниеЭлемента... ". Самый простой способ изучить внутреннюю структуру, воспользоваться точкой остановки и просмотреть все реквизиты. - ознакомьтесь https://programmist1s.ru/otladka-1s/

Answer (score 0):

Подсказка, на будущее. Чтобы определить, с каким реквизитом связан объект формы, можно нажать ПКМ на элементе и выполнить команду "Перейти" (либо быстрая клавиша F12)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фокус перейдет в окно реквизитов и покажет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В моем примере элемент "Вид цены" связан с реквизитом "Вид цены", который находится в табличной части "Товары" объект.